# Django multiple image uploads in admin without 3rd party apps

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, imagefield

I need your help once again and I really hope that someone could offer a step by step guide easy to follow because I am a beginner.

I am trying to create a photography portofolio and I do not have any idea on how to go about multiple imagefield uploads in admin. What I want to end up with is a Photography app that will enable me to upload multiple images at once under one category (e.g. "Landscape"). It would be nice if I could also resize them using Django in the process of uploading, so that I would have to resize them in Photoshop. Then I want to be able to use masonry to display all my images and filter them by category using isotope.

I am looking for a solution without having to install 3rd party solutions like django-admin-multiupload or jQuery File Upload. Could you please help me start out? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example model that would work.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Image(models.Model):
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

For the admin site, you can use [inline admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) so that while editing the category, you can upload multiple images in the same page without third party library.

```
class ImageInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Book

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ImageInline,
    ]
```

Comment: Hello Edwin. Your solution sounds wonderful, thank you for helping me out! I will try it right away. I have one small request. From what I understand the inline admin helps with multiple uploads in the same page but I still have to select de one by one. Am I right? I want to be able to select 10 photos at a time and upload them. I have a feeling that Formsets might help but I have no idea where to start. Can you please include that in the code above? Thank you Edwin!

Comment: Hey Edwin, I have tried your method. It is not what I am looking for. I want to upload them all at one. This way I have to select them one by one which is time consuming. Do you have any other ideas?